# se vende -- is this passive or is "se" == it?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, gramática, vocabulario

On a car I saw a label: **se vende**

In such cases, how do I  know *precisely* what this means:

1) it sells --> active voice

or

2) it's sold / it's being sold --> passive voice

Is it possible to answer this question?

In other words, what's "se" here: "it" or indicator of passive voice?

Comment: Why do you think "se" could mean it?  Do you have an example of where it could definitively mean that?  Generally, the only potential confusion with se is between impersonal and passive voice (*se estudia X* could mean *one studies X*, or *X is studied*), but that's not a problem here.

Comment: @guifa how do I say "it" then in Spanish? literaly, the "it"

Comment: @guifa examples-wise -- I've seen and heard some, but I don't have them with me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this interesting [**link**](http://www.rae.es/consultas/se-venden-casas-se-buscan-actores-frente-se-busca-los-culpables) that answers your question

The content is in Spanish. Let me try to translate a relevant part

> a) **oraciones de pasiva refleja**. En estas oraciones, la forma **se**
>   precede a un verbo en tercera persona del singular o del plural, según
>   sea singular o plural **el elemento nominal que aparece junto al verbo y
>   que es su sujeto gramatical**. Por tratarse de una forma de pasiva, esta
>   construcción solo se da con verbos transitivos: ***Se vende casa de campo***
>   / Se venden casas de campo. Normalmente el sujeto de estas oraciones
>   denota cosa, pero puede denotar también persona indeterminada: *Se
>   buscan actores para la película.*

In English

> a) Phrases in **reflective passive voice**. In these phrases, "**se**"
>   precedes a verb in the third singular or plural form, depending on **the
>   nominal element that appears by the verb and that is the gramatical
>   subject**. Being a passive voice, this contruction only appears with
>   transitive verbs: *Se vende casa de campo / Se venden casas de campo* [A
>   country house is being sold / Country houses are being sold]. Usually
>   the subject on these phrases denotes a thing, but it can denote an
>   undetermined person too: *Se buscan actores para la pelicula* [Actors
>   are being hired for the movie]

I don't know how this kind of phrases are named in English and I'm not sure of the last phrase translation, surely there is a more idiomatic way of saying it, but I hope this helps.

Notice that the example *Se vende casa de campo* matches your phrase *Se vende*.
**Se** does not mean **it**, "se" is not the subject, as stated in the D.R.A.E text that I quoted. The subject of "Se vende" is the object being sold, the car in your case. The complete sentence is "Se vende (este coche, el que tiene pegado este cartel)".

So the answer to your question "*what's "se" here: "it" or indicator of passive voice?*" is:
**According to the D.R.A.E is an indicator of passive voice, it's not the subject.**

The phrase in English "it sells very well" can be translated to Spanish as "Se vende muy bien" or "Vende muy bien". Notice that in both cases the third person pronoun "it" is omitted.

Comment: that doesn't answer my question. I already know it and this is also implied in my question.

Comment: @nylypej Your question: "what's "se" here: "it" or indicator of passive voice?" My answer: According to the D.R.A.E, "se" is an indicator of passive voice. I don't get how the linked reference does not answer your question.

Comment: ok, that answers my question. how do I say "it" in spanish?

Comment: @nylypej What do you mean by "it"? Can you construct a complete sentence to provide context? In your example "Se vende", the object being sold is the car. We can question about what exactly is being sold with: ¿Qué es lo que se vende? What's the object being sold? Lo que se vende es el coche.

Comment: You've never heard of the word "it" in English? I'm not asking about a way of how to express something! I asked: how to say "it"?

Comment: @nylypej Yes, I've heard that word, of course. But its translation depends on the context. "Ello" is the pronoun that refers to a thing in Spanish and usually it's omitted.

Comment: `Lo que se vende es el coche.` --> `se vende coche` --> `it's being sold` --> `(it) sells` --> how to say "it" explicitly in this case?

Comment: Lo que se vende es el coche -> Se vende el coche -> Este (coche) se vende o Él se vende. Él is the third person pronoun in Spanish. "Ello" is the canonical third form used for things but you can use "él" instead. The phrase "(it) sells" makes no sense, it (the car) is not selling anything. It should be "he/she is selling his/her car" [Active voice]

Comment: `it sells` is a correct phrase in terms of grammar and meaning

Comment: @nylypej You're right. My mistake. "it sells very well" in Spanish is "Se vende muy bien" or "Vende muy bien". In both cases the explicit third person "it" representing the object being sold dissapears.